# Github pages Jekyll static blog outdated

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages

I setup a Jekyll blog on Github-Pages 5 months ago. It was working at that time, and I though it would be a nice place to post things.

Long story short, I wrote a first post, but then I never used, until yesterday when I wanted to check that all was working fine, but it was not. I also could not run Jekyll locally.

I do not use ruby on my daily basis ,so they were outdated. I though maybe if I update it and generate the site again everything is going to be working fine.

I updated ruby from 2.1.2 to 2.2.1, and I tried other things to make it work. Now is working locally, but throwing this

```
Generating...
Defaults: An invalid front-matter default set was found:
[{"scope"=>{"path"=>"_posts/"}, "values"=>{"author"=>"Agustin Gambina"}}]
Defaults: An invalid front-matter default set was found:
[{"scope"=>{"path"=>"_posts/"}, "values"=>{"author"=>"Agustin Gambina"}}]
```

I also added a Gemfile to the root directory

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

require 'json'
require 'open-uri'
versions = JSON.parse(open('https://pages.github.com/versions.json').read)

gem 'github-pages', versions['github-pages']
```

When I run

```
github-pages health-check
```

I get this

> Checking domain littlebit.me...
>   Uh oh. Looks like something's fishy: Domain does not resolve to the GitHub Pages server

Does anyone know why it happened to me that is not working anymore? was because it was outdated and something changed?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your _config.yml file :

```
-
  -
    scope:
      path: "_posts/scala"
    values:
      author: Agustin Gambina
```

Must be :

```
-
  scope:
    path: "_posts/scala"
  values:
      author: Agustin Gambina
```

This is not a fatal error, so your site build, but your rule is not applied.

Concerning the health-check, it works for me as it checks littlebit.me that resolve to github IPs.

```
$: dig littlebit.me
...
littlebit.me.       1800    IN  A   192.30.252.154
littlebit.me.       1800    IN  A   192.30.252.153
```

If it doesn't work on your PC, you may have a DNS problem. Maybe you've set a bad value in your hosts file ?

Comment: thank you for your answer. I changed the config file and stopped throwing the invalid front-matter. On the other hand I feel like a dumb because I forgot that I touched the hosts file